# Python concatenation of variable and string

Tags: python, concatenation

```
for i in range (0,len(list4)):
  ws.write(1, 0, datetime.now(), style1)
  ws.write(2, 1, 1)
  ws.write(2, 2, xlwt.Formula("A3+B3"))
  wb.save('example.xls')
```

how do i generalize (A3+B3) ?

```
'"A" + i' + '"B" + i'
```

Is this correct???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'A%(row)d+B%(row)d' % {'row': 3}
```

or

```
'A{0}+B{0}'.format(3)
```

Comment: +1 I'm upvoting because I think the versions of the string formatting routines that you use are cleaner than my very old-fashioned ways. I prefer the first one where a meaningful name can be used.

Comment: Just to point out you can still use named fields in the newer [PEP 3101](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101) `.format` syntax: `"A{row} + B{row}".format(row=3)`. The `0` just means "use the first value".

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
ws.write(2, 2, xlwt.Formula("A" + str(i) + "+B" + str(i)))
```

Or more idiomatically:

```
ws.write(2, 2, xlwt.Formula("A%d+B%d" % (i,i)))
```